# Unknown modifier in my code

Tags: php, modifier

```
<? php
    $Src = 'images/pages/clients/logos/clnt_aljareera_img.jpg';
    $pttn= '/&Src:'.$Src.'/';
    $string=preg_replace($pttn,'',$string,1);
?>
```

//output Error: Unknown modifier 'p' in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your string contains a whole mess of `/` which would need to be escaped as `\/` when using `/` as the regex delimiter. Instead of `/` as the regex delimiters, use something which won't occur in your string like `~` for example.  You *must* choose a delimiting character which is guaranteed *not* to appear in `$Src`, however.  You might be safer even with `|` than with `~`.

```
$Src = 'images/pages/clients/logos/clnt_aljareera_img.jpg';
// Delimit the regular expression with ~
$pttn= '~&Src:'.$Src.'~';
$string=preg_replace($pttn,'',$string,1);
```

What has happened is your regex delimited by `/` encounters a `p` immediately after `images/` because it thinks it has reached the closing delimiter.  The next word `pages` is mistakenly treated as a string of regex modifiers.

PHP sees the regular expression:

```
/&src:images/pages
```

Comment: light-speed. thanks bud.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the space in your opening php-tag.

Comment: That almost looks like the problem (and it is a problem), but the unknown modifier is a result of `images/p` where the regex thinks it encounters its closing `/` delimiter followed by a `p`.

Comment: You're right, the opening php-tag "only" results in a syntax error.. it just jumped right into my eye and I guess he would have needed to fix it anyways ;-)

Comment: Really, this would cause `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE`